# How can I cast between interface?

Tags: c#, interface

there are interface a, b, c;

// defined.
interface d : b, c;

class C1 : a, b, c;

// I want to cast to interface d;

```
var t = c1 as d;
```

// t is null.

Comment: I have been using c#.

Comment: To cast to an interface, do   (d)c1

Comment: In your code, `C1` does not implement `d`.  An object cannot be cast to an interface that its type does not implement.

Answer (score 1):

```
d t = c1;
```

would do the trick.

For example in

```
IEnumerable<int> iList = new List<int>();
```

iList would not have List specific methods such as Add